# Glob for copying files from a subfolder

Tags: visual-studio-code, glob

I am using a VSCode extension called Deploy Reloaded.

It uses globs to copy files.

Before it worked fine for me with this glob

`**/*.ex*`

I am just using this as an example, in reality I have multiple similar globs for different extensions.

this would mean it would copy files from the base folder, no matter what subfolder they were in, that matched this pattern.

e.g.

`\Samson\a.exq`

copied to

`(dest folder)\Samson\a.exq`

the problem now is that I need to copy files from a folder within the base folder. How can I make a glob for that?

e.g.

`\Temple\Samson\a.exq`

copied to

`(dest folder)\Samson\a.exq`

Comment: why don't you ask in an issue of the extension

Comment: @rioV8 the github repo has this message "This repository has been archived by the owner. It is now read-only."

Comment: then you have to examine the source code to see how it uses the glob patterns, you have to add a path modifier search/replace

Comment: thanks (_this is to exceed min comment length requirements_)